# pandas.DataFrame: How to merge rows with a common column value in the same pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame that looks like that:

| index | projectid | question | answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 'q1' | 'str1' |
| 1 | 1 | 'q2' | 'str2' |
| 2 | 1 | 'q3' | 'str3' |
| 3 | 2 | 'q1' | 'str4' |
| 4 | 2 | 'q3' | 'str6' |

And I would like to format it like that:

| index | projectid | question1 | answer1 | question2 | answer2 | question3 | answer3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 'q1' | 'str1' | 'q2' | 'str2' | 'q3' | 'str3' |
| 1 | 2 | 'q1' | 'str4' | None | None | 'q3' | 'str6' |

Not every project has the same number of question but questions are shared for each project. So when a specific question isn't in a project, I would like cells to be filled up with None values.

I didn't found any way to do it with join or concat, but I don't know how to properly use it.

I would like to improve my pandas skills so my question is:
Is there any way to do it with pandas treatment or doing it manually by treating my DataFrames with iterrows is the only way ?

Thank you !

Comment: try google pandas pivot, pandas reshape dataframe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumcount` before pivoting to get your suffixes:

```
df['idx'] = df.groupby('projectid').cumcount() + 1
df = df.pivot(index='projectid',columns='idx')[['question','answer']]
df.columns = [''.join(map(str, col)) for col in df.columns]
print(df)
```

Output::

```
          question1 question2 question3 answer1 answer2 answer3
projectid
1              'q1'      'q2'      'q3'  'str1'  'str2'  'str3'
2              'q1'      'q3'       NaN  'str4'  'str6'     NaN
```